# Grails : Overriding getter method in domain class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I can't override grails getter method and becoming crazy.

What I want is use a double value and a string value to get a formatted data, but when I'm typing my override method into String, the double value is null and when into double, it obviously get me an error because a String is returned !

I get a domain class like that :

```
class Project {
    ...
    String currency
    Double initialTargetAmount
        ...
}
```

First Override method (initialTargetAmount is null in this case) :

```
//@Override Comment or uncomment it does not make any change to the behaviour
public String getInitialTargetAmount() {
        println "${initialTargetAmount} ${currency}" // display "null EUR"
        "${initialTargetAmount} ${currency}" // initialTargetAmount is null
}
```

Second method :

```
//@Override Comment or uncomment it does not make any change to the behaviour
public Double getInitialTargetAmount() {
        println "${initialTargetAmount} ${currency}" // display "1000.00 EUR"
        "${initialTargetAmount} ${currency}" // Error : String given, Double expected
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Snite

Comment: Can you work your second method out. You wrote it with a `String` in return section which is obviously the same à the previous method.

Comment: I did not understand what you want me to do (sorry, I'm French) : I know that the second method is bad because not correctly typed, what I want to underline is the fact than typing it whith Double return me good values, but null value when typing into String, but the fina return I want is a string because of concatenation

Comment: Alors, parlons peu mais parlons bien ;-) I don't think that could be a method return type problem. How do you create your objects ? Does they come from a database ? Are you in a controller ? Please explain the context...

Comment: Mouarf ;-) Getters method are into the Domain class. This domain class is create on my own. No problem when loading normal getters before, I just want to ovverride domain class's getters, so all of that happen into the domain class definition. When return type is Double, I get correct information (display is good into println) but it can't work because it's a double which is expected, and I return a String. When return type is String, my number is null, and I can't say why. All of this happen into the Domain class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has dynamic getters and setters.

So, `initalTargetAmount` field "creates" automatically a `Double getInitialTargetAmount` method. Which is why it works when you have the `Double` return Type. But when you set `String`, `getInitialTargetAmount` automatically refers to a field `String initalTargetAmount` which doesn't exist

Try changing the name of the method, for example `getInitialAmountWithCurrency()` and it will work. Maybe your best bet will be to override `toString()` method ^^

Comment: Works fine, and give me a good explanation of what happen, feel less idiot :-) But is there a method to ovveride getter without take a different name ? A way to say to Grails : "Ok, that's a String return, but I want you to get my double value, please don't look at a String value" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your getter should be always the same type of your field, and it's noot a good approach to change the getter like this, because Grails (Hibernate internally) will understand that your object instance changed and will try to update it ( it will check the old and new values).

You're trying in fact is to have a String representation of your amount, so you have a couple of options to this:

#### 1 - A new method

Creating a new method that returns String will not interfere in the hibernate flow and you can use it anywere.

```
class Project {
    ...
    String currency
    Double initialTargetAmount
    ...
    String displayTargetAmount() {
       "${initialTargetAmount} ${currency}"
    }

}
```

#### 2 - TagLib

Depending on your needs, you could create a [TagLib](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#taglibs) to make this custom representations of your class. This can include html formatting.

```
class ProjectTagLib {
  static namespace = "proj"

  def displayAmount = { attrs ->
    if(!attrs.project) {
      throwTagErrro("Attribute project must be defined.")
    }

    Project project = attrs.remove('project')
    //just an example of html
    out << "<p>${project.initialTargetAmount} , ${project.currency}</p>" 

  }

}
```

Comment: Nice explanation, I'll proceed whith an other method name.